# Web Audio-Stopping Oscillator Sound

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Trying to create a pulsing tone. Found some help from another posting here ([web audio api plays beep, beep,... beep at different rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672781/web-audio-api-plays-beep-beep-beep-at-different-rate)). Needed to adapt the script. Came up with a satisfactory result that plays and pulses a tone. Cannot figure out a function to stop the tone: .stop() used with oscillators doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.

Here's my code:

```html
<html>
<body>
<button id = "start1" onclick='tone();'>Play</button>
<button id = "stop1" onclick='stopper();'>Stop</button>
<script>
function tone(){
var context = new AudioContext();
var abc = context.createOscillator();
abc.frequency.value = 325;
var xyz = context.createOscillator();
xyz.type='sine';
xyz.frequency.value = 10;
var gain = context.createGain();
var ramp = context.createGain();
abc.connect(gain);
gain.connect(context.destination);
xyz.connect(ramp); 
ramp.gain.value = 0.3;
gain.gain.value = 0.3;
ramp.connect(gain.gain);
abc.start(0);
xyz.start(0);
}
function stopper()
{
abc.stop();
xyz.stop();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are referencing a variable in the stop function that doesn't exist in the scope of the the function. You need to create the variables outside the tone function so they can be accessed in `stopper()`

Comment: Thank you mix3d. That worked. Moved variables outside. Newbie using Web Audio API.

Comment: It's not an audio API issue, it's a variable scope issue. Glad to help.

Comment: Yes, definitely a variable scope issue. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving comment to answer:

The AudioAPI is not the problem, it's a simple variable scoping problem.

Variables created in a function are not accessible outside that function, and the `stopper()` function can't access the abc/xyz variables.

```html
<html>
<body>
<button id = "start1" onclick='tone();'>Play</button>
<button id = "stop1" onclick='stopper();'>Stop</button>
<script>
let context = null;
let abc, xyz;

function tone(){
    context = new AudioContext();
    abc = context.createOscillator();
    abc.frequency.value = 325;
    xyz = context.createOscillator();
    xyz.type='sine';
    xyz.frequency.value = 10;
    var gain = context.createGain();
    var ramp = context.createGain();
    abc.connect(gain);
    gain.connect(context.destination);
    xyz.connect(ramp); 
    ramp.gain.value = 0.3;
    gain.gain.value = 0.3;
    ramp.connect(gain.gain);
    abc.start(0);
    xyz.start(0);
}
function stopper()
{
    abc?.stop();
    xyz?.stop();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Additionally, since the user can click the stop button before the start button, possibly before the variables are initialized, it is useful to use the _Optional Chaining_ pattern to prevent "Cannot read property <prop> of undefined" errors. Using `abc?.stop()` will fail gracefully if `abc` is null or undefined